# how do you make a randomized photo slide show in python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a randomized slideshow in **Python**

current working code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from itertools import cycle
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


with open('list.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().strip('[]')
    images = [i.strip("\" ") for i in lines.split(',')]


photos = cycle(ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(image)) for image in images)

def slideShow():
  img = next(photos)
  displayCanvas.config(image=img)
  root.after(1200, slideShow) 

root = tk.Tk()
root.overrideredirect(True)
width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
height = root.winfo_screenwidth()
root.geometry('%dx%d' % (1920, 1280))
displayCanvas = tk.Label(root)
displayCanvas.pack()
root.after(1000, lambda: slideShow())
root.mainloop()
```

I tried randomizing it by changing `img = next(photos)` to `img = random.choice(photos)`
I got the error `NameError: name 'random' is not defined`

full randomized code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from itertools import cycle
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import random

with open('list.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().strip('[]')
    images = [i.strip("\" ") for i in lines.split(',')]


photos = cycle(ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(image)) for image in images)

def slideShow():
  img = random.choice(photos)
  displayCanvas.config(image=img)
  root.after(1200, slideShow) 

root = tk.Tk()
root.overrideredirect(True)
width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
height = root.winfo_screenwidth()
root.geometry('%dx%d' % (1920, 1280))
displayCanvas = tk.Label(root)
displayCanvas.pack()
root.after(1000, lambda: slideShow())
root.mainloop()
```

How should I go about properly converting my slide show to a random one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use `shuffle()` from random which is part of the Python standard library.

```
import random
random.shuffle(images)
```

Just keep in mind that shuffle works in place and returns `None`

Comment: where should i put that? sorry im very new to coding and i am also sleep deprived.

Comment: Imports should go at the top of the file. You should shuffle the list after you create it and before you want to use it so I would place it before '
photos = cycle(ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(image)) for image in images)'